# How to get a debug flow of execution in C++

Tags: c++, workflow, debugging, trading

I work on a global trading system which supports many users. Each user can book,amend,edit,delete trades. The system is regulated by a central deal capture service. The deal capture service informs all the user of any updates that occur.

The problem comes when we have crashes, as the production environment is impossible to re-create on a test system, I have to rely on crash dumps and log files.

However this doesn't tell me what the user has been doing.

I'd like a system that would (at the time of crashing) dump out a history of what the user has been doing. Anything that I add has to go into the live environment so it can't impact performance too much.

Ideas wise I was thinking of a MACRO at the top of each function which acted like a stack trace (only I could supply additional user information, like trade id's, user dialog choices, etc ..) The system would record stack traces (on a per thread basis) and keep a history in a cyclic buffer (varying in size, depending on how much history you wanted to capture). Then on crash, I could dump this history stack.

I'd really like to hear if anyone has a better solution, or if anyone knows of an existing framework?

Thanks
Rich

Comment: Please I beg you, don't use a macro.

Comment: how else do I ensure it's removed when I no longer need it? #ifdefs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution sounds pretty reasonable, though perhaps rather than relying on viewing your audit trail in the debugger you can trigger it being printed with atexit() handlers. Something as simple as a stack of strings that have __FILE__,__LINE__,pthread_self() in them migth be good enough

You could possibly use some existing undo framework, as its similar to an audit trail, but it's going to be more heavyweight than you want. It will likely be based on the command pattern and expect you to implement execute() methods, though I suppose you could just leave them blank.

Answer (score 0):

Trading systems usually don't suffer the performance hit of instrumentation of that level. C++ based systems, in particular, tend to sacrifice the ease of debugging for performance. Otherwise, more companies would be developing such systems in Java/C#.

I would avoid an attempt to introduce stack traces into C++. I am also not confident that you could introduce such a system in a way that would not affect the behavior of the program in some way (e.g., affect threading behavior).

It might, IMHO, be preferable to log the external inputs (e.g., user GUI actions and message traffic) rather than attempt to capture things internally in the program. In that case, you might have a better chance of replicating the failure and debugging it.

Are you currently logging all network traffic  to/from the client? Many FIX based systems record this for regulatory purposes. Can you easily log your I/O?

Comment: yeah I have logging and crash dumps already. The stack trace wouldn't be a real stack trace, it would be a hand rolled version. As I'm interested in what happens to things throughout the workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest creating another (circular) log file that contains your detailed information.  Beware that this file will grow exponentially compared to other files.

Another method is to save the last *N* transactions.  Write a program that reads the transaction log and feeds the data into your *virtual* application.  This may help create the cause.  I've used this technique with embedded systems before.

Comment: my other idea for recreating the problem was to record update messages sent from the server on the live multicast, and then play them back to my client on a seperate multicast. I'm undecided if this would help or not.